# ¿Como ordenar varios td de forma vertical en una tabla HTML con PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo dos campos llamados question1_a5s2 y question1_a5s3 en mi Base de datos, entonces en estos se guarda información de 3 inputs diferentes. ejemplo:

question1_a5s2:
Lunes, Martes, Miercoles

question1_a5s3:
Jueves, Viernes, Sadado

Ahora lo que trato de hacer es mostrar esos datos en una tabla de forma vertical, algo asi:

| question1_a5s2 | question1_a5s3 |
| --- | --- |
| Lunes | jueves |
| Martres | viernes |
| Miercoles | sabado |

Ya tengo en separarlos por comas y dar el salto, pero no logro ponerlos en la estructura mencionada. Dejo mi código.

```
 $aux = $sessionsEndForShows['question1_a5s2'];
$quitar_ultima_coma = substr($aux, 0, -1);
$cadena = explode(',', $quitar_ultima_coma);
$cantidad = count($cadena);

if ($cantidad >= 1) {
    $cadena_final = explode(',', $aux );
    $cantidad_final = count($cadena_final);
}else{
    $quitar_ultima_coma_final = substr($aux, 0, -1);
    $cadena_final = explode(',', $quitar_ultima_coma_final );
    $cantidad_final = count($cadena_final);
}

            <table border="1">

                    <tr>
                        <?php for ($i=0; $i < $cantidad_final; $i++) { 
                         $num = $i + 1;
                           echo '<td style="Display:block;">
                          -&nbsp; '. $cadena_final[$i] .'<br>
                        </td>';
                          } ?>
                    </tr>

                </table>
```

En este ejemplo solo traigo los datos del campo question1_a5s2 y me los muestra como lo mencione, pero falta el campo question1_a5s3. ¿Alguna idea de como real izarlo?

Answer (score 1):

Tu código es un desastre, estás mezclando html sin cerrar el php y viceversa. Te voy a explicar un truco para hacer tablas en php y alguna cosilla más para que seas mas eficiente, simplemente crea una variable donde pondremos todo el html de la tabla y cuando lo tengamos lo imprimimos en pantalla, de esta forma quedará mucho más claro. Te dejo el código comentado para que veas lo que hace cada cosa.

```
    // asignamos valor a las variables según tu pregunta, fíjate que tiene comas al principio y al final.

    $question1_a5s2 = "Lunes, Martes, Miercoles,";
    $question1_a5s3 = ", Jueves, Viernes, Sábado";

    // eliminamos los espacios que puedan haber en las variables.

    $question1_a5s2 = str_replace(' ', '', $question1_a5s2);
    $question1_a5s3 = str_replace(' ', '', $question1_a5s3);

    //comprobamos si hay una coma al principio o final, si es así la eliminamos
    //trim se suele utilizar para eliminar espacios, pero nos permite poner el caracter que queremos eliminar, esto lo hace más claro y elegante.

    $question1_a5s2 = trim($question1_a5s2, ',');
    $question1_a5s3 = trim($question1_a5s3, ',');

    //generamos un array con las palabras de cada variable

    $partes_question1_a5s2 = explode(",", $question1_a5s2);
    $partes_question1_a5s3 = explode(",", $question1_a5s3);

    // Utilizaremos la variable $html para ir añadiendo fragmentos de la tabla

    $html = "";

    //utilizamos $html .= que es lo mismo que $html = $html.
    //creamos la tabla.

    $html .= "<table border='1'>";

    //creamos la cabecera.

    $html .= "<tr>";
    $html .= "<th>question1_a5s2</th>";
    $html .= "<th>question1_a5s3</th>";
    $html .= "</tr>";

    //para el contenido, como sabemos de antemano que las dos variables contienen 3 elementos cada una,
    //podríamos simplemente escribir las 3 líneas, pero vamos a suponer que pueden variar los elementos.
    //Tenemos que averiguar cual de las dos tiene mas elementos, count nos dirá cuantos tiene cada array.

    $cantidad_question1_a5s2 = count($partes_question1_a5s2);
    $cantidad_question1_a5s3 = count($partes_question1_a5s3);
    $maximos_elementos=0;

    //Comparamos que una variable sea mayor que la otra, si es así esta tiene el máximo,
    //En caso contrario o la otra es la mayor o son iguales.

    if ($cantidad_question1_a5s2 > $cantidad_question1_a5s3) {
        $maximos_elementos = $cantidad_question1_a5s2;
    } else {
        $maximos_elementos = $cantidad_question1_a5s3;
    }

    //Ahora ya sabemos cual es el máximo de elementos, así que utilizaremos esta como tope para el bucle.

    for ($i = 0;$i < $maximos_elementos;$i++) {

    // añadimos el html de apertura de linea

        $html .= "<tr>";

    // Ahora comparamos que $i sea menor que la cantidad de elementos de la primera variable, si es así ponemos el contenido
    // en caso contrario, ponemos una casilla en blanco.   

        if ($cantidad_question1_a5s2 > $i) {
            $html .= "<td>".$partes_question1_a5s2[$i]."</td>";
        } else {
            $html .= "<td></td>";
        }

    // Lo mismo con la segunda variable    
        if ($cantidad_question1_a5s3 > $i) {
            $html .= "<td>".$partes_question1_a5s3[$i]."</td>";
        } else {
            $html .= "<td></td>";
        }    

    // cerramos la línea y el bucle.    

        $html .= "</tr>";
    }

    // cerramos la tabla

    $html .= "</table>";

    // Imprimimos en pantalla el html de la tabla.

    echo $html;
```

Fíjate bien en el código y en como se estructura la tabla a trozos para luego imprimirla de una vez. Un saludo.